# jquery how to get input previous and new value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I am facing an issue in javascript. I want to get value of input field `previous value and current value`.

My Code:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#licensekey', function () {
                var prev = $(this).data('val'); //undefined
                var current = $(this).val();
                console.log("Prev value " + prev);
                console.log("New value " + current);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> License Key</label>
<input id='licensekey' type='text' class='input'>
```

what should i do?
anyone help me.

Comment: You don't have any attribute with name `data-val` in your input box .

Comment: what i should do? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10606400/swati)

Comment: You should be setting `$(this).data('val')` with the  `$(this).val();` so that next change you can get the previous value.

Comment: it is not working [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12354911/eldar)

Comment: @devs1994 : please be more precise in the problem you face if you want help. The more details you gave, the more chances to have a good solution you will have.

Comment: What is that "issue" you are talking about? Anything not wokring with the given code?

Comment: Off-topic: that should be `licencekey` - "license" is something different

Answer (score 1):

You could store `prev` in a variable like so:

```js
    var prev = null;
    $(document).on('change', '#licensekey', function () {
        var current = $(this).val();
        console.log("Prev value " + prev);
        console.log("New value " + current);
        prev = current;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <label> License Key</label>
    <input id='licensekey' type='text' class='input'>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks i try [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855085/andrew-arthur)

Answer (score 1):

You never set `$(this).data('val', current)` so there is no reason to expect it to change from undefined

```js
$(document).on('change', '#licensekey', function () {
                var prev = $(this).data('val'); //undefined first time only
                var current = $(this).val();
                console.log("Prev value " + prev);
                console.log("New value " + current);
                // store current for next change
                $(this).data('val', current)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> License Key</label>
<input id='licensekey' type='text' class='input'>
```

Comment: thanks i try your code [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl)

Comment: can you solve this `undefined` issue on first time [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl)

Comment: Well is there an initial value on the input? None is shown. If there is none what would be expected?

Comment: @devs1994 your question is like saying `var x;` gives `undefined` - how can I solve it.  You solve it by giving it a value to start with, but we can't tell you what that value should be.    Add `data-val="starting value"` to the `input`.